# Using constants as default function values in PHP

Tags: php, function, constants

Is this legal?

```
<?php

function ftw($foo = 'pwnage', $nub = MENU_DEFAULT_VALUE, $odp = ODP_DEFAULT_VALUE) {
      //lots_of_awesome_code
}

?>
```

where `MENU_DEFAULT_VALUE` and `ODP_DEFAULT_VALUE` are constants defined previously in the file.

Comment: yeah, but I was having problems in a function that uses this and I thought maybe it was technically possible but against best practices.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, that is legal.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function
>   call.

Constants fit that bill perfectly.

Comment: Any reason/documentation for not being able to refer to the constant using ```static``` but just via ```self```, when setting defaults for a class method argument?

Comment: @Kamafeather `static` is subject to late static bindings, making it inconstant.

Answer (score 22):

In an OOP context, you can also use a class member constant as a default method argument value.

```
class MyClass
{
    const A = 1;

    public function __construct($arg = self::A)
    {
        echo $arg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

why don't you try ?

Still, just in case you can test right now, the following code :

```
define('MENU_DEFAULT_VALUE', 10);
define('ODP_DEFAULT_VALUE', 'hello');

function ftw($foo = 'pwnage', $nub = MENU_DEFAULT_VALUE, $odp = ODP_DEFAULT_VALUE) {
    var_dump($foo);
    var_dump($nub);
    var_dump($odp);
}

ftw();
```

gives this output :

```
string 'pwnage' (length=6)
int 10
string 'hello' (length=5)
```

So I'd say that, yes, it is valid :-)

Comment: In the context of a class method I found out that is not possible to refer to the constant via ```static```, but just using ```self```; this ```myMethod($arg1 = static::MY_CONST)``` won't work. Do you know any valid explanation for this different behaviour?